# Best direction forward for "On Hold" question

Tags: support

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Thousands of Random MAC Addresses in Wireshark WLAN packet capture (single channel)](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/59863/thousands-of-random-mac-addresses-in-wireshark-wlan-packet-capture-single-chann)

I had flagged for moderator action to move the question to SuperUser or Security.SE as per their judgement, but nothing has happened.

So  I'd like advice, and corresponding moderator action, on the best direction forward for the question:

1. Close this original question. Ask entirely new, smaller, *concise* questions about networking *theory* that may still be on-topic for this SE, or get moved to SU if inappropriate.
2. Move the original question over to SuperUser and let the SU community decide whether the question is answerable or not?
3. I think this is the action that is perhaps *expected* in the context of the issue, that the question be *edited* down to be concise? Unfortunately that is not possible without completely rewriting the question, removing "unnecessary" data etc. And an extensive rewrite merits closure and simply asking a new question. In other words option 1.

   One way or another (Closure or Movement), I'd request action on this question immediately, as I do need to resolve some issues in a time-sensitive manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to simply ask your question on your chosen SE site. The SE guidelines are to only migrate questions with answers or comments worth preserving. You can simply **Edit**, **Copy All**, and **Paste** into a question on your chosen site.

Also, if I migrate this question to another SE site, it is going to be rejected back to NE by the moderators of the new site because it is too broad to answer without simply guessing, and I do not wish to antagonize moderators on other SE sites.

I can think of several possibilities about what is happening, but with the current information, it is pure speculation, which is off-topic here. SE sites are meant for asking questions with enough information to get specific answers, not opinions.

Comment: I see. I was wary of my question being marked as duplicate if it was simply reasked on SU or some other place, even if I had edited as the source material/data is largely the same, and the concerns the same, it would just have different words. That's why I was waiting for it to be closed here or moved if that were the protocol. I'll proceed with drawing up smaller questions and ask them on home-networking sites. Educated speculations are always welcome for novices, you know, as they can provide invaluable _correction_ of the investigative field. Unfortunately SE is not for that.